# How do I disable the body mask on the Rain model?

Tags: 3d-view, masking

I'm trying to learn a little Blender and I downloaded the [Rain v2 model](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da) to experiment. It appears to be a fantastically well-outfitted model, however there's some basic stuff I don't understand. When I disable the scarf, for example, there's the body mesh underneath but when I disable the shoes, it appears as if there's nothing there even though I can see in edit mode that there's a full body mesh. Deleting the shoes doesn't make any difference.

Is the hidden part masked somehow, or hidden? How do I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

With the armature selected, in the CloudRig panel, under Outfits, you can choose if you want to mask or display the legs and arms. This is shown [in the walktrough video at 1:00](https://youtu.be/ZvG956AFc4Q?t=62).

### How it is done

The object "GEO-rain_body" has a Mask modifier (the 3rd one in the modifier pile). It masks every vertex belonging to the "mask_modifier" vertex group.

The two modifiers above, "mask_arms" and "mask_legs", add those respective vertex groups to "mask_modifier" ; but only in Viewport, not in Render.

Then things become a little bit more complex, because their visibility in viewport is ***driven*** *(that's why the icon appears purple)* by the value of a custom propertie of the armature. So, you just need to modify that property in the CloudRig panel, with the armature selected (so you don't need to select the object, go to modifiers and manually unset them).

Comment: Thanks @thibsert! The mask modifiers under GEO-rain_body did the trick indeed.